# How to transfer data from C# to android app in both directions

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a small web service using technology asp .net mvc 3.
At the same time with the service I am developing android application.

Please tell me, how to implement the transfer of data between the service on asp .net mvc 3 and android application, in both directions.

**The specific objective:**

I need at any given time in my service to the asp .net mvc 3, get the coordinates of the device where you installed and running my android app.

Sorry for my english.

And thank you for your answers!